# Not enough memory (less than 50 m on heap) error message in weka 3.8

Tags: java, memory, weka, heap-memory

I am using weka 3.8. when I apply association rules on my dataset, an error message appears which says that (not enough memory. less than 50m left on heap. please load a smaller dataset or use a larger heap size).

Comment: So, allocate a larger heap?  What is stopping you from doing that?

Comment: you mean assign higher value to heap in the (.ini) file of weka?

Answer (score 0):

In your `RunWeka.ini` you can change

```
javaOpts=%JAVA_OPTS%
```

to

```
javaOpts=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xmx2048m
```

The parameter `-Xmx` says how much memory your vm is allowed to use.

See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/man/java.html for more info about this and other parameters.

Comment: I am trying that, but the merror message still appears.

Comment: What happend if you increase to ```-Xmx8192m```?